# Как проверить на наличие обьекта и при его наличии склонировать?

Tags: javascript

У меня имеется, код с помощью которого я клонирую обьект. Как сделать так, что-бы мой код работал только тогда, когда объект есть? Понимаю что как-то нужно сделать проверку на его наличие. Как?

```
  container = document.querySelector(".header-user");
        const container2 = document.querySelector("#header");
        const simpleCopy = container.cloneNode(true);
        container2.appendChild(simpleCopy);
        simpleCopy.className = "";
        simpleCopy.innerHTML = "";
```

Comment: Если объекта нет, методы DOM возвращают `null` или `undefined`.

Comment: Напишите, какой объект надо проверять, я ответ напишу.

Comment: Peter Kolosov, вот этот я клонирую .header-user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно сделать так:

```js
let container = document.querySelector(".header-user");
if (container) { // если container будет null или undefined, то этот блок не будет выполняться
        const container2 = document.querySelector("#header");
        const simpleCopy = container.cloneNode(true);
        container2.appendChild(simpleCopy);
        simpleCopy.className = "";
        simpleCopy.innerHTML = "";
}
```

`if` выполняется только тогда, когда условие истинно, а условие `null` или `undefined` является ложным, следовательно, это то, что вам нужно.

Comment: Если что-то непонятно, спрашивайте.

Comment: @User не молчите, если вам помогло.

Comment: Peter Kolosov, пока проверить не могу. Как проверю отпишусь.

Comment: @User окей. Проверьте, когда сможете.

Comment: Peter Kolosov, спасибо! Всё работает.

Comment: @User не за что. Если можете, пожалуйста, поставьте ещё плюсик (стрелка вверх :)

Comment: Peter Kolosov, уже сделал

Comment: @User Спасибо!)

Comment: Надеюсь, я никому не надоедаю со своими просьбами "поставьте галочку и поставьте плюсик"))

Comment: Peter Kolosov, мне точно нет.